# Does the Bar Council of India enroll candidates who passed 10+2 with vocational subjects?

Tags: india, education, bar-association, bar-admission

As a vocational student in 10+2 (I.T CBSE), I want to pursue BA LLB. Is there any problems for vocational students, who have passed their 12th, to enroll in Bar council of India?

Do I meet the criteria to enroll after passing BA LLB? What is the criteria to study BA LLB? Does that need specific ARTS stream in 10+2 or can Information Tech (CBSE) 10+2 students also qualify to study law?

If one wants to pursue BA LLB after 12th and subjects in 10+2 being vocational, is the eligibility not met?

I want to study law further but the admissions teacher is telling me I could face problems later.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple questions here, so I've picked those that seem to be most relevant.

**What is the criteria to study BA LLB?**

- As well as being an Indian national, one needs at least 45% aggregate in their [12th (a.k.a 10+2)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher_Secondary_School_Certificate#:%7E:text=In%20India%2C%20HSC%2FIntermediate%20is,CBSE%2C%20Council%20for%20the%20Indian) to be eligible for the [CLAT](https://law.careers360.com/articles/clat-eligibility-criteria/amp) entrance exam - a pass being a prerequisite for enrollment in to an under graduate five-year BA LLB course.
- There are are no restrictions for vocational students, and [CBSE](https://www.cbse.gov.in/) 10+2 marks are recognised for the CLAT.

**Do I meet the criteria to enroll after passing BA LLB?**

- After successful completion of the BA LLB, one may enroll with their state Bar Council. The process is fairly straightforward, as long as the application forms and supporting documents are in order. [This is the process for the Bar Council of Delhi](https://delhibarcouncil.com/the-membership/how-to-apply/), with the other states following the same or similar pattern.
- After all this, in order to practice law one then needs to pass the [All India Bar Examination](http://allindiabarexamination.com/#) - see this [FAQ](http://www.barcouncilofindia.org/about/first-all-india-bar-examination/all-india-bar-examination-frequently-asked-questions/#whoshould) for further guidance on this (but things may change during the five years it takes to do the BA LLB).